# Update profile avatar DRF and Vue.js

Tags: python, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios

I am not fully understanding why I can not update an image url in my DRF api. I am using djoser for the api endpoints and activation, django rest framework and vue.js for the frontend with axios making the API requests. I believe (and I may be wrong!) that I cannot make patch requests with Axios using FormData() so from googling I have found another method but Im still getting HTTP 500 error and Django error:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/users/me/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/markmckeon/Django_Stuff/Relate/environment_3_8_8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/markmckeon/Django_Stuff/Relate/environment_3_8_8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/markmckeon/Django_Stuff/Relate/environment_3_8_8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/markmckeon/Django_Stuff/Relate/environment_3_8_8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/markmckeon/Django_Stuff/Relate/environment_3_8_8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/markmckeon/Django_Stuff/Relate/environment_3_8_8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/markmckeon/Django_Stuff/Relate/environment_3_8_8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/markmckeon/Django_Stuff/Relate/environment_3_8_8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/markmckeon/Django_Stuff/Relate/environment_3_8_8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djoser/views.py", line 175, in me
    return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/markmckeon/Django_Stuff/Relate/environment_3_8_8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 82, in partial_update
    return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/markmckeon/Django_Stuff/Relate/environment_3_8_8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 68, in update
    self.perform_update(serializer)
  File "/Users/markmckeon/Django_Stuff/Relate/environment_3_8_8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djoser/views.py", line 149, in perform_update
    super().perform_update(serializer)
  File "/Users/markmckeon/Django_Stuff/Relate/environment_3_8_8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 78, in perform_update
    serializer.save()
  File "/Users/markmckeon/Django_Stuff/Relate/environment_3_8_8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 208, in save
    assert self.instance is not None, (
AssertionError: `update()` did not return an object instance.
```

What I am unsure of is whether this is a backend issue with how the image file is handled or if it is how the frontend is submitting the file?

Here is the my serializers.py:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile       
        fields = ("__all__")

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'profile', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {"password":{'write_only': True}}

    

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        parser_classes = (MultiPartParser)
        if 'profile' in validated_data:
            nested_serializer = self.fields['profile']
            nested_instance = instance.profile
            nested_data = validated_data.pop('profile')

            nested_serializer.update(nested_instance, nested_data)


            return super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data) 

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

As you can see I am updating a nested User model to keep the user profile and user details together.

Vue.js:

```
methods: {

     updateAvatar() {

          const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
          const image = this.fileName
          const formData = new FormData();
                    const data = {
                    profile: {
                        avatar: image,
                        },
                    username: this.user_profile[0]["username"],
                    password: token
                  };
          console.log("Pre send: ", data);

          for(let dataKey in data) {
            if(dataKey === 'avatar') {
              // append nested object
              for (let previewKey in data[dataKey]) {
                formData.append(`avatar[${previewKey}]`, data[dataKey][previewKey]);
              }
            }
            else {
              formData.append(dataKey, data[dataKey]);
            }
          }

          const base = {
                    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
                    headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                    },
                    xhrFields: {
                      withCredentials: true
                    }
                  };
          const axiosInstance = axios.create(base);
                      axiosInstance({
                        url: "/api/v1/users/me/",
                        data: formData,
                        method: "patch"
                      })
          // axios

          //   .patch(`/api/v1/users/me/`, formData)
            
            .then((response) => {
              const newArray = response.data;
              console.log("Userchanges: ", newArray);
            })

            .catch((error) => console.log(error.response));
    }
  },
```

And finally my DRF user instance:
[image: DRF User profile]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to unindent the `super` call in your `update` method:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser)
    if 'profile' in validated_data:
        ...

    # unindented
    return super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

EDIT:

`ProfileSerializer` should work correctly, although I am not sure about `nested_serializer = self.fields['profile']` and updating a related instance through explicit `.update()`. Try rewriting your code to something like this:

```
if 'profile' in validated_data:
    nested_instance = instance.profile
    nested_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
    Profile.objects.filter(pk=nested_instance.pk).update(**nested_data)
```

If the problem remains, then recheck your request payload coming from front-end.

Comment: Thanks Ersain that was the issue. Cant believe I missed that! It is patching now with out error, but Im not updating the DRF with the new image? Am i missing something in the backend?

Comment: @MarkMcKeon show your ProfileSerializer, the issue should be there

Comment: please see the updated code above

Comment: @MarkMcKeon hi, just updated the answer

Comment: thanks for your help. But I think the ```nested_serializer = self.fields['profile']``` line allows me to update the profile without having to add an avatar. When I omit that line I can not update the avatar from the DRF api directly. I have been able to upload an image from the endpoint but Im still having issues with the frontend. Im starting to think it is my payload from vue.js. It is a nested user object.

Comment: I found the problem - it was the way I was handling the payload in my frontend in FormData().